# Cordova - console.log file does not exist when using iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, cordova

When I run `cordova run ios --emulator` the script exits successfully and tells me, that there's a file (`console.log`) inside `platforms/ios/cordova` but there's no such file although I used console.log several times in my code.

Also, Safari does not show my device in the developer menu when it's connected via USB and running the app. I used `cordova run ios --device` to run the app.

Am I looking in the wrong place? Does the script lie? :D

Comment: try with `cordova prepare ios`